# Basic auth with SolrNet NuGet package

Tags: basic-authentication, solrnet

I had been using a copy of SolrNet 0.4.0.2002 that I had downloaded locally a long while ago (I don't remember from where) as well as a copy of HttpWebAdapters 0.4.0.2002 (also of unknown origin), and I'm upgrading the application where I use those.  I tried installing the NuGet package for SolrNet, which got me 0.4.0.4000.  It didn't have class `HttpWebAdapters.BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory`, so I figured I'd install the HttpWebAdapters NuGet package, also 0.4.0.4000, but I then get an error about types being in both `HttpWebAdapters.dll` and `SolrNet.dll`.  There isn't a 0.4.0.2002 version in the default NuGet repository.

How can I use the NuGet packages to perform basic authentication with SolrNet?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/solrnet/2XnuMpqStfc/56sK2uZP-lIJ

Comment: @MauricioScheffer - I've having trouble understanding what the resolution is here..  In SolrNet's history I see BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory but it's no longer there.  Are we supposed to always roll our own?  Is the HttpWebAdapters NuGet package in any way related to your project?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidPeters BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory is in https://www.nuget.org/packages/SolrNet/0.5.0-alpha1

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, would you mind making an answer so I can give you credit?